# AVAudioPlayerNode completion handler timing

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

Does the `scheduleFile(_:at:completionHandler:)` execute the handler before or AFTER the audio file has finished playing? Does it execute it before or after stopping the player/engine?

Comment: Did you try it? What were the results?

Comment: The handler is executed after the audio file has started and before it is done playing.

Comment: From iOS 11, you can specify the completion handler callback type in `scheduleFile(_:at:completionCallbackType:completionHandler:)`

Comment: set the type to `.dataPlayedBack` to call the completion handler after playback of the file has finished

Answer (score 1):

On Apple's documentation it says this:

> Called after the player has scheduled the buffer for playback on the
>   render thread or the player is stopped

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayernode/1388422-schedulebuffer)

Comment: Yes, I know. Could you dissect that? What is the "buffer" or the "render thread"